# How to develop Gear VR app with emulators?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I currently can't afford to buy a Gear VR headset with samsung's first class phones like: S6, S7 or S8. But I wanna start developing.

I tried installing Gear VR app using unity in Genymotion emulator. App got installed in genymotion but app didn't show in dual/stereoscopic mode.

While, when I installed the same app on S6 edge hardware device then it seems to work fine because it showed a message on screen to enter phone into Gear VR device.

So, Can I test Gear VR app developed using unity in any emulator. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you own a S6 Edge that has the Gear VR software already installed on it you can put your Gear VR software in to [developer mode](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-troublesh-device-run-app-outside/) which will allow it to run VR apps without being inserted in to a headset.

> 1. Go to Settings > Application Manager
> 2. Select Gear VR Service
> 3. Select Manage Storage
> 4. Click on VR Service Version several times until the Developer Mode toggle shows up
> 5. Toggle Developer Mode
>
> Note: If you do not see the Developer Mode toggle switch after tapping VR Service Version several times, close
>   Gear VR Service and relaunch, and you should see it.

To get the software installed you just need to find some other person's Gear VR or a display model and plug your phone in, this will cause the software to install. You can then take your phone home and develop using the developer mode on your own.